# how to automatically copy pictures and videos from specific folders on Android to Windows PC through USB

Tags: android, file-synchronization

I spent 2 days to find a software that would have those very basic requirements but I failed:

1. automatically move pictures from folder X and Y on the phone to folder Z on my PC
2. automatically move videos from folder A and B on the phone to folder C on my PC
3. **cherry on the cake**: destination folder can be sub folders created dynamically based on the date of the medias. but it's not that important in my case, I have one folder per year only.

it seems reasonnable right?
In my case X and Y would be the DCIM folder on my SD card + the whatsapp/whatsapp images/ folder on my internal storage.
A and B would be the DCIM folder too on my SD card + the whatsapp/whatsapp video/ folder on my internal storage.

Most software do ask the destination folder, and sometimes 2, 1 for pictures and 1 for videos, but I didn't find any that would allow me to set a list of SOURCE folders :-(

one example is the defaut import feature on Windows 10. It takes ages to scan ALL folders, so it shows all pictures even one related to software (like maps etc) and do not allow to remember source folders to monitor.
same with syncios,  mobilego...

any idea?

Comment: [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite) could match this. At least without the cherry. Though I must admit I never tried the "move" (here called "delete after successfull transfer").

Comment: FolderSync works with the cloud. I would like to sync with my PC and through USB cable (no wifi nor mobile connection required)

Comment: FolderSync also works without cloud (that's how I use it with my Linux machine). But probably not via USB cable. Are the directories you want to sync mounted on your machine in some way? I'm not familiar with how to do that on Windows (as pointed out, I'm using Linux). If not even WiFi is acceptable, then I'm out here, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK using WIFI and your Android is rooted, [SambaDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=berserker.android.apps.sambadroid) can share an android folder as an SMB share so you can map it (`\\SAMBADROID`) as a network drive on your PC, then use robocopy or any standard sync software.